# SQL Convert list of events into durations (MSSQL 2008)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Let's say I have a table with all kinds of events and their starttimes:

```
EventTime              EventCode         EventDescription
---------              ---------         ----------------
2014-01-23 00:03:32    430               Running
2014-01-23 00:04:35    430               Running
2014-01-23 00:06:37    430               Running
2014-01-23 00:11:45    430               Running
2014-01-23 00:32:46    721               Stopped
2014-01-23 00:34:49    721               Stopped
2014-01-23 00:41:52    430               Running
2014-01-23 01:03:54    721               Stopped    
2014-01-23 01:04:55    430               Running
```

From this data, I would like to get the startTimes and durations of all Intervals. Meaning, the startTime of a record with eventCode 721 and the startTime of the first successive event with eventCode 430 and the other way around, something like:

```
START                 END                   STATUS
-----------           ----------            ----------------
2014-01-23 00:03:32   2014-01-23 00:32:46   Running
2014-01-23 00:32:46   2014-01-23 00:41:52   Stopped
2014-01-23 00:41:52   2014-01-23 01:03:54   Running
2014-01-23 01:03:54   2014-01-23 01:04:55   Stopped
```

I've already seen usage of the OVER syntax, but in the examples I've seen it was used for successive rows in a dataset. The Table a have can have a number of the same statuses after each other.

What would be the best (and most performant) way to convert that data as in the example? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, Should have mentioned it. MSSQL 2008

Comment: 2008 doesn't support syntax like *MIN(col) OVER (ROWS 1 PRECEDING)* yet?

Comment: @dnoeth - likely, 2008 will never support that syntax. That's because it's been succeeded by the 2012 and 2014 versions which do have support for the `ROWS` syntax

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Of course MS will not backport to 2008, i just didn't know when they introduced the enhanced syntax :-)

Comment: 3 of the 4 rows in the expected output have a start and end time that have different event codes, but in the second row both times originate from a record with an event code of 721. I am struggling to get your exact logic. Can you elaborate further please?

Comment: @GarethD Mistake. My apologies. Should be correct now. The EndTime of a 'stopped' interval should be the starttime of a 'running' interval

Comment: FYI, this is a variation of a [Gaps and Islands](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/gaps-and-islands/hot) problem. Although both answers provide solve your problem, neither actually explains how it is being solved, but knowing what the name of the problem is should guide you to some comprehensive explanations of how ROW_NUMBER (or DENSE_RANK) are used to solve the problem.

Comment: @GarethD I used both answers below to figure out how the query actually works, but the name will indeed help me understand better. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it

```
WITH cte AS 
(
  SELECT eventcode, eventdescription, MIN(eventtime) starttime, MAX(eventtime) endtime,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY MIN(eventtime)) rnum
    FROM
  (
    SELECT t.*,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY eventtime) rnum,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY eventcode ORDER BY eventtime) grnum
      FROM table1 t
  ) q
   GROUP BY eventcode, eventdescription, rnum - grnum
)
SELECT t1.starttime, t2.starttime endtime, t1.eventdescription status
  FROM cte t1 JOIN cte t2
    ON t1.rnum = t2.rnum - 1
 ORDER BY starttime, endtime
```

Output:

```
|                      STARTTIME |                        ENDTIME |  STATUS |
|--------------------------------|--------------------------------|---------|
| January, 23 2014 00:03:32+0000 | January, 23 2014 00:32:46+0000 | Running |
| January, 23 2014 00:32:46+0000 | January, 23 2014 00:41:52+0000 | Stopped |
| January, 23 2014 00:41:52+0000 | January, 23 2014 01:03:54+0000 | Running |
| January, 23 2014 01:03:54+0000 | January, 23 2014 01:04:55+0000 | Stopped |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2e4883/9)** demo

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to peterm's answer, just one less ROW_NUMBER...

You might change the LEFT join to INNER:

```
WITH cte (EventTime, EventCode, EventDescription, rn, rn2) AS 
 (
   SELECT
      EventTime, EventCode, EventDescription,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY EventTime) AS rn,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EventCode ORDER BY EventTime) AS rn2
   FROM Table1
 )
SELECT MIN(t1.EventTime), MAX(t2.EventTime), t1.EventDescription
FROM cte AS t1 LEFT JOIN cte AS t2
ON t2.rn = t1.rn+1
GROUP BY t2.rn-t1.rn2, t1.EventDescription
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: when I change the second status to running, the results are all messed up, with wrong statusses, because your grouping has a bug: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f4dae/2

Comment: Solution: ad T1.Eventdescription in the groupby

Comment: That corrects it. However, Found another small difference in behaviour with @peterm 's answer: when the last complete interval is running, and the current interval (ie. endTime = NULL) is also in status running, then it gets split up by your query. The other query takes them together. Not really a bug or error, just a difference :-) Anyway, thanks for your effort.